# Drools rule to check a collection with compound value restriction

Tags: collections, contains, rules, drools

I want to check if a collection contains **not** three elements. In java I would do

```
!(collection.contains("s1") && collection.contains("s2") && collection.contains("s3"))
```

How can I do this with drools? I searched for two hours and tried anything but can't find a solution for this "simple" problem. I found the "Compound Value Restriction" which is what I exactly need, but it does not work for collections and the "contains" operator.

I would appreciate your answers.

Nathanael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what the Java code does:

```
Collection( this not contains "s1" ||
            this not contains "s2" ||
            this not contains "s3")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I was missing the forest through the trees!

Answer (score 0):

I think, You can take rule dialect "java".
   Following sample can help you.

```
global java.util.ArrayList responseList

rule "checkCollectionRule"
    dialect "java"
    salience -1

    when

        eval(ifContains(responseList, val1, val2.....))

    then

        responseList.add(new Boolean("true"));

end


function Boolean ifContains(List responseList, String val1, String val2,....) {
    return (responseList.contains("s1") && responseList.contains("s2") && responseList.contains("s3"));

}
```

Hope this help. 
   Thanks.